# Merging values from multiple HashMaps into a single List

Tags: java, hashmap

I have 4 separate hashmaps all of the same type. I would like to merge the values of them all into a single list. I know how to set a List to hashMapOne.values(), but this doesn't help me here since I need to add all values from all 4 lists. Can I do this without looping and individually adding each one?

```
HashMap<String, MyEntity> hashMapOne = new HashMap<String, MyEntity>();
HashMap<String, MyEntity> hashMapTwo = new HashMap<String, MyEntity>();
HashMap<String, MyEntity> hashMapThree = new HashMap<String, MyEntity>();
HashMap<String, MyEntity> hashMapFour = new HashMap<String, MyEntity>();

List<MyEntity> finalList = new ArrayList<MyEntity>();
```

Comment: And what do you expect to do on collisions?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans There won't ever be collisions since it is just all of the values which will always be their own entities in memory, even if the properties are exactly the same it doesn't matter, I don't care about the keys.

Comment: So what do the values map to?

Comment: If you only want the `MyEntity` side of all the HashMaps, consider `ArrayList.AddAll()` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai Lets say an Id to keep it simple, yes there might be the keys that are the same across hashmaps but it shouldn't matter as far as my business logic is concerned.

Comment: So... all you care about is `new arraylist(h1).addall(h2).addAll(h3)` etc.? If so: that's part of the standard ArrayList API. Give its method list a read-over, it's worth knowing what it supports out of the box.

Comment: @Gus that is exactly what I am looking for I believe.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Correct!

Comment: If you have keys that are the same, previous values will be overwritten. Maps don't handle collision well.

Comment: It should be noted that @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans solution will still iterate underneath the hood.

Comment: At the end of the day I just want all of the Entities to be in a single list, I do not care about the keys from the HashMap because they were just for temporary use. Thanks!

Comment: naturally; I assume anyone who doesn't want to iterate over a list actually means "I don't want to write my own for loop".

Comment: Lol... Agreed @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Answer (score 4):

```
List<MyEntity> finalList = new ArrayList<MyEntity>();
finalList.addAll(hashMapOne.values());
finalList.addAll(hashMapTwo.values());
finalList.addAll(hashMapThree.values());
finalList.addAll(hashMapFour.values());
```

Answer (score 3):

If I were you, I'd just use [`Stream#of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of(T...)) for all [`Map#values`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#values()), and then call [`Stream#flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) and [`Stream#collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.stream.Collector)) to transform it to a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html):

```
List<MyEntity> finalList = Stream.of(hashMapOne.values(), hashMapTwo.values(), 
                                     hashMapThree.values(), hashMapFour.values())
      .flatMap(Collection::stream)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```